# How to manipulate browser url in Inertia.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, vuejs3, inertiajs

I've been using an `IntersectionObserver` to update the `url` of my `SPA` while the user scrolls down the page like so:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section')
const options = {
    threshold: 0.5
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            router.push('#' + entry.target.id)
        }
    })
}, options)
sections.forEach(section => {
    observer.observe(section)
})
```

but how do I do this in `Inertia.js` since it doesn't have the `router.push` method? I'm using `Inertia` with a `Vue 3` frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes seem to be preserved by Inertia when navigating from frontend: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/pull/257

However, this does not seem to be the case from the server: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/729#issuecomment-1017619220

If this is not a problem for you, can you try simply visiting the same URL and adding the hash?

```js
const id = entry.target.id
const urlWithFragment = `${url}#${id}`

Inertia.visit(urlWithFragment)
```

By default, the http method is `get`, but you can customize it:

```js
Inertia.visit(urlWithFragment, {method: 'post'})
```

If you use ziggy you can easily recover the current route:

```js
const currentRoute = route().current()
const url = route(currentRoute)

const urlWithFragment = `${url}#${id}`
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method, in my case I have multi tabs page.

```js
import { router } from '@inertiajs/react'


    const handleTabChange = (e) => {
        setInrtiaUrl(
            router.visit(
                route('dashboard', [user.id, { tab: e }]) // { tab: '1' } is the query parameter
            )
        )
        setIndex(e)
    }
```

then set `handleTabChange` on your `onChange={(event, value) => handleTabChange(value)}` method

url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard?tab=1

[image]